# How to change colors of pip error messages in windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, pip, systemcolors

The error messages printed by pip in my Windows PowerShell are dark red on dark blue (default PowerShell background). This is quite hard to read and I'd like to change this, but I couldn't find any hint to how to do this. Even not, if this is a default in Python applied to all stderr-like output, or if it's specific to pip.

My configuration: Windows 10, Python 3.9.0, pip 20.2.3.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: [Get PIP Source Code](https://github.com/pypa/pip) and edit it according to your need compile or whatever and use it.

Comment: Of course this is always possible, but my changes would be gone with each upgrade of pip. After some research in the pip forum I saw, that those are ANSI escape sequences, so it might not be possible to change the behavior from pip, aside from disabling color output..

Answer (score 0):

Coloring in pip is done via ANSI escape sequences. So the solution to this problem would be, to either change the way, PowerShell displays ANSI colors or the color scheme pip uses. Pip provides though a command-line switch '--no-color' which can be used to deactivate coloring the output.